# Jenkins pipeline withenv and step not run with environmental variables specified

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline script which uses the following step within a withEnv block:

```
withEnv(['Repository_name=Repo', 
    'capability_squish=c:\\Squish',"build_working_directory=${workspace}"]) {
    bat "python test.py"
    step([$class: 'SquishBuilder', 
        abortBuildOnError: false,  
        extraOptions: '', 
        host: '127.0.0.1', 
        port: '4322', 
        resultFolder: "${workspace}\\squish-test-reports\\", 
        skipTestCases: false, 
        snoozeFactor: '1', 
        squishConfig: 'demo_gui', 
        testCase: '', 
        testSuite: "${workspace}\\suite_default"])
}
```

The issue is that the step does not run with the Environmental vars that i am expecting, the line

```
bat "python test.py"
```

Executes and outputs the expected vars and works as expected, does anyone know why the step would not use the environmental variables ?
Or know if there is something that i do doing incorrectly here ?
I'm guessing it an issue with Jenkins or the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of posting this is an issue in Jenkins pipeline.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29144